# Find 2 square numbers with certain distance

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to find 2 sqare numbers with a certain distance without trying every square number?

Example:

$$
a^2 + 204 = b^2
$$

Comment: Can't you find a pair for every number? I guess you have to specify you're looking for integers. In that case, I have no idea. Use a computer if you want an answer, keep looking if you want a strategy other than brute force.

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange to $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)=204.$ It suffices to find the solutions where $a$ and $b$ are positive. List all pairs of integers that multiply to $204:$

$$ (1,204) \ , \ (2,102) \ , \ (3, 68) \ , \ (4, 51) \ , \ (6,34) \ , \ (12,17) $$

Now try each case: E.g. for $(1,204)$ try to solve $a-b = 1, a+b=204$ for integers $a,b.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

We have
$$a^2+204=b^2\iff b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)=204=2^2\times 3\times 17$$
What's the possibilities of the factors $b-a$ and $b+a$?

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, then note that 
$$a^2+204=b^2\iff (b-a)(b+a)=204.$$
Both $b-a$ and $b+a$ are integers and they have to be divisors of $204=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 17.$

(Since $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, you'll notice that $b-a$ and $b+a$ have to have the same parity.)

So, in general, for a given $N\in\mathbb N$, to find pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z$ such that 
$$b^2-a^2=N\iff (b-a)(b+a)=N,$$
we only need to consider the divisors of $N$. The number of the pairs $(a,b)$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

$$b^2 - a^2 = 204 \Rightarrow (b-a)(b+a) = 204$$

Since $204 = 2^2·3·17$ we have some options:

$\begin{cases}a + b = 204 \\b-a = 1 \end{cases}\hspace{2.9cm}\begin{cases}a + b = 1 \\b-a = 204 \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}a + b = 102 \\b-a = 2 \end{cases}\hspace{2.8cm}\begin{cases}a + b = 2 \\b-a = 102 \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}a + b = 68 \\b-a = 3 \end{cases}\hspace{3cm}\begin{cases}a + b = 3 \\b-a = 68 \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}a + b = 51 \\b-a = 4 \end{cases}\hspace{3cm}\begin{cases}a + b = 4 \\b-a = 51 \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}a + b = 17 \\b-a = 12 \end{cases}\hspace{3cm}\begin{cases}a + b = 12 \\b-a = 17 \end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, if $a^2+n=b^2$, then $n=(b-a)(b+a)$. Now, the difference between the two factors $b-a$ and $b+a$ is $2a$, which is even; this means that $b-a$ and $b+a$ must be either both even, or both odd. This, in turn, means that $n$ must be either odd, or divisible by $4$.

And if this is the case, then you can always find suitable integers $a,b$.

For instance, if $n=204$, which is divisible by $4$, we want a factorisation (any factorisation) into two even numbers: $204=6 \times 34$, say. Then solve the equations:
$$b-a=6$$
$$b+a=34$$

to get $a=14,b=20$. Checking: $20^2-14^2=400-196=204$.

If $n$ is odd, say $n=123 = 3 \times 41$, then we solve

$$b-a=3$$
$$b+a=41$$

to get $a=19,b=22$. Checking: $22^2-19^2=484-361=123$.

And if $n$ is even but not divisible by $4$, there is no solution in integers.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation as $b^2-a^2=204\implies (b+a)(b-a)=204$. Therefore $(b+a)$ and $(b-a)$ are two factors of $204$. This can be stated as

$b+a=f_1$

$b-a=f_2$

Where $f_1f_2=204$.Solving this,$b=\frac{f_1+f_2}{2},a=\frac{f_1-f_2}{2}$. This means that $f_1+f_2$ and $f_1-f_2$ are both even, which implies $f_1$ and $f_2$ are either both even or both odd. The factors of 204, which form $(f_1,f_2)$, are

$(\pm1,\pm204),(\pm204,\pm1),(\pm2,\pm102),(\pm102,\pm2),(\pm3, \pm68),(\pm68\pm3),(\pm4, \pm51),(\pm51,\pm4),(\pm6,\pm34) ,(\pm34,\pm6) , (\pm12,\pm17),(\pm17,\pm12)$, where the $\pm$ is either both positive or both negative in each bracket. The only values which have the same parity are

$(2,102),(-2,-102),(102,2),(-102,-2),(6,34),(-6,-34),(34,6),(-34,-6)$

Plugging these into the formulas for $a$ and $b$ above, the possible values of $(a,b)$ are

$(-50,52),(50,-52),(50,52),(-50,-52),(-14,20),(14,-20),(14,20),(-14,-20)$, which simplifies to

$(\pm14,\pm20),(\pm50,\pm52)$, where the $\pm$s are independent of each other.